# Why does not pipe work with 'find' and 'ls'

Tags: bash, ls, pipe, xargs

Why does not pipe work with 'find' and 'ls'
If I do `find . -name *foo* | ls -lah` , it does a ls on `$PWD` and not the output of find.

The solution however is `find . -name *foo* | xargs -r ls -alh` or can use exec.

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept it. Don't put the answer in your question or the comments! :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please consult the [manual page of `ls(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/ls.1.html)! The `ls` command takes it's arguments on the *command line* not on *standard input* (i. e. file descriptor 0).

When you run

```
<SOME_COMMAND> | ls [OPTIONS...]
```

you instruct the command interpreter to create a *pipe* (`|`) from the the standard output of the left command to the standard input of the right command (here: `ls`). But `ls` disregards its standard input and inspects its command line parameters, finding no positional argument and listing the *current working directory* (stored in the `PWD` environment variable by shell interpreters like Bash) instead.

The [`xargs(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/xargs.1.html) takes *tokens* (delimited by whitespace characters if not specified otherwise) from its standard input stream and adds them as parameters to the command line of another command to run. In your case, the `ls` command given to `xargs` receives a set of path names on its command line and performs its task on them as documented by the manual.

Bonus: The "command" option `-ls` to GNU `find` will print the matching paths in a similar fashion to `ls -dils` (see [`find(1)`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/find.1.html)).

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use command substitution.
Syntax: *command* *options* $(*output of another command*)

For this example:

```
ls -lah $(find . -name *foo*)
```

Comment: We are a Q&A site not a discussion forum.  [Our model is to provide a library of questions and answers about Ubuntu *without chitchat or distraction*](https://askubuntu.com/tour).  Can you edit your question and distill it down to what's necessary to answer the question?

Comment: Unfortunately this breaks if any matching file names contain white space.